# Merge multiple csv files with rows sorted by the time specified in one of the columns

Tags: bash

I have multiple files a.csv, b.csv, c.csv.
All these files contains rows formatted the same way:

12345798SOMEID24597;ThisisaTest;2021/11/04 17:07:05;SOMETHINGELSE

How could I merge all these files into a single file with the rows sorted by the date.

Comment: you've obviously got some code (per your 'answer') so what's the real question? or does your 'answer' not work? if you're still having issues then consider adding sample (input) data, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -t ';' -k 3 *.csv > sorted.csv
```

Is fine. You don't need `-n` (`--numeric-sort`), because the numbers are all the same fixed width.

Comment: I'd use `-k 3,3` to sort _only_ on the 3rd column. Otherwise you're sorting from the 3rd column to the end. Depends what OP wants.